# Multi-texturing in PyOpenGL using a GLSL shader

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, textures, pyopengl

I would like to be able to combine two textures in a GLSL fragment shader.  I am currently using PyOpenGL and everything i've done up to this point using shaders has worked fine.

I am running into difficulty when I try to access multiple textures from the fragment shader, for instance, the following shader displays the correct texture minus the blue pixels:

```
uniform sampler2D my_texture1;
uniform sampler2D my_texture2;
void main()
{
    vec4 color1 = texture2D(my_texture1, gl_TexCoord[1].st);
    vec4 color2 = texture2D(my_texture2, gl_TexCoord[2].st);
    if (color1.b > 0.8)
        discard;
    gl_FragColor = color1;
}
```

but

```
uniform sampler2D my_texture1;
uniform sampler2D my_texture2;
void main()
{
    vec4 color1 = texture2D(my_texture1, gl_TexCoord[1].st);
    vec4 color2 = texture2D(my_texture2, gl_TexCoord[2].st);
    if (color2.b > 0.8)
        discard;
    gl_FragColor = color2;
}
```

results in a  blank screen.

I have  a feeling that the problem might lie in how i am passing the texture uniforms to the shader but cant for the life of me work out why the first texture works but the second doesn't. Below is the full program.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from Image import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *

ESCAPE = '\033'
global size
size = 512

def drawQuad(B,T,L,R):
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1, 0.0, 0.0); glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE2, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(B, L,  1.0);       ## Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1, 1.0, 0.0); glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE2, 1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f( T, L,  1.0);       ## Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1, 1.0, 1.0); glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE2, 1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f( T,  R,  1.0);       ## Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1, 0.0, 1.0); glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE2, 0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(B,  R,  1.0);       ## Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glEnd()

def InitGL(Width, Height):
    print "Vendor:   " + glGetString(GL_VENDOR)
    print "Renderer: " + glGetString(GL_RENDERER)
    print "OpenGL Version:  " + glGetString(GL_VERSION)
    print "Shader Version:  " + glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)

    if not glUseProgram:
        print 'Missing Shader Objects!'
        sys.exit(1)

    global program
    program = compileProgram(
        compileShader('''
                void main()
                {
                    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
                    gl_TexCoord[1] = gl_MultiTexCoord1;
                    gl_TexCoord[2] = gl_MultiTexCoord2;
                }
        ''',GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
        compileShader('''
                uniform sampler2D my_texture1;
                uniform sampler2D my_texture2;
                void main()
                {
                    vec4 color1 = texture2D(my_texture1, gl_TexCoord[1].st);
                    vec4 color2 = texture2D(my_texture2, gl_TexCoord[2].st);
                    if (color1.b > 0.8)
                        discard;
                    gl_FragColor = color1;
                }
    ''',GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER),
    )

    #bmp texture 1
    image = open("rgb.bmp")
    ix = image.size[0]
    iy = image.size[1]
    image = image.tostring("raw", "RGBX", 0, -1)
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1)
    global my_texture1
    my_texture1 = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, my_texture1) 
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL)
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

    #bmp texture 2
    image = open("rgb2.bmp")
    ix = image.size[0]
    iy = image.size[1]
    image = image.tostring("raw", "RGBX", 0, -1)
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2)
    global my_texture2
    my_texture2 = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, my_texture2) 
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL)
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

def DrawGLScene():
    global frame, testvar, my_texture1,my_texture2
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
    glUseProgram(program)
    myUniformLocation1 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "my_texture1")
    glUniform1i(myUniformLocation1, 1)
    myUniformLocation2 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "my_texture2")
    glUniform1i(myUniformLocation2, 2)
    glViewport(0, 0, size,size)
    glClearDepth(1.0)
    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()  
    glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -30.0, 30.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity() 
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    drawQuad(-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0)
    glutSwapBuffers()

def keyPressed(*args):
    global texturenumber, shadernumber, frame
    # If escape is pressed, kill everything.
    if args[0] == ESCAPE:
        sys.exit()

def main():
    global window
    glutInit(sys.argv)
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)
    glutInitWindowSize(size,size)
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)
    window = glutCreateWindow("Multitexturing")
    glutDisplayFunc(DrawGLScene)
    glutIdleFunc(DrawGLScene)
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPressed)
    InitGL(size,size)
    glutMainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Press 'ESC' key to quit."
    main()
```

Comment: Have you checked for OpenGL errors using `glGetError()`? What happens if you just draw the second texture (without the `if`)? You should try to narrow down your problem (e.g. remove the unused texture and see what happens). Can you make sure if your second texture is loaded correctly?

Comment: @kroneml `glGetError()` returns a 0 which as I understand it means no error?  When just drawing the texture using the shader (no `if`) the first texture is displayed correctly and the second just displays a black screen.  If I disable the shader and use `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1)` or `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2)` in the draw call the right texture is applied to the quad so it seems the textures are both successfully loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually unbind the second texture before using it:

```
def DrawGLScene():
    global frame, testvar, my_texture1,my_texture2
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
    [...]
```

After your initialization, texture unit 1 has `my_texture1` assigned and texture unit 2 `my_texture2`. The active texture is still texture 2. So by calling `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)` you unbind the texture from the active texture unit 2.

What you shoud do is this:

```
def DrawGLScene():
    global frame, testvar, my_texture1,my_texture2
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, my_texture1) 
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, my_texture2)
    [...]
```

You could also simply remove the last four lines (after `global frame, testvar, my_texture1,my_texture2`) since your init routine takes care of this. However, if you bind and unbind any other textures in your code you have to do the texture unit activation and texture binding as above.

Comment: That's it sorted, much appreciated. I was binding to texture 0 to try to make sure that the shader was doing the texturing but that backfired completely!

Comment: Don't call `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`, it only changes the *fixed-function* pipeline, and it has no effect on sampling with shaders. @StuGrey

Comment: Tim is of course right, I just ignored the `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` because it will not hurt, but it shouldn't be there. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm always unsure what calls become redundant when I stop using the fixed-function pipeline.